# Indexing in a for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing, boolean

I am trying to get the index of the most left numerical and non-numerical lists within a dictionary.
I tried the following below but in the first for loop it does not give me the right index and the second for loop does not seem to assign anything to the ind_num variable.
Where are my mistakes?

Thank you for your help!

```
dic = {"hello": 1, "column": [[1, float], [3, str], [4, int], [2, str]]}

columns = dic["column"]
for col in columns:
    if col[1] != [float, int]:
        ind_non = columns.index(col)  # getting the index for the first non-numerical column
        break

for col in columns:
    if col[1] == [float, int]:
        ind_num = columns.index(col)  # getting the index for the first numerical column
        break

print(ind_non)
print(ind_num)
```

Comment: `if col[1] != [float, int]:` In your own words, with the given input, what values do you expect `col[1]` to have? When you compare those to `[float, int]`, what logic do you expect to apply? For example, what do you think should be the result of `int != [float, int]`? Why? Also, what *problem are you trying to solve* by storing this kind of data? What does a value like `[3, str]` *actually mean* to you and your program?

Comment: What are you trying to display in ind_non and num? [1,float] here 1 or the index of this list in column?

Comment: @Neeraj the index of the list in column

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I would like ```int == [float, int]``` to give me TRUE. And I expect col[1] to access the second value of the list i.e. the datatype. 
The goal is to get the index of the lists in column so that I can use this index later for other operations.

Comment: "I would like int == [float, int] to give me TRUE." Okay, but why? In your own words, what does `==` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the points to remember in general:

1. Always declare and set default variable which you will be using in the conditional statements. Ie. in your code `ind_non` and `ind_num` would throw an error if the elements are not present in the list 'column'.
2. `col[1] == [float, int]` is wrong, you are comparing `int == [float, int]`. Instead check if int is present in [float, int] like I've mentioned below.

   ```
    dic = {"hello": 1, "column": [[1, float], [3, str], [4, int], [2, str]]}

    columns = dic["column"]
    ind_non = None
    ind_num = None
    for col in columns:
        if col[1] not in [float, int]:
            ind_non = columns.index(col)  # getting the index for the first non-numerical column
            break


    for col in columns:
        if col[1] in [float, int]:
            ind_num = columns.index(col)  # getting the index for the first numerical column
            break

    print(ind_non)
    print(ind_num)
    # 1
    # 0
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
col[1] != [float, int]:
```

Doing like this is wrong. You can write it with `or` keyword or `any`.

```
dic = {"hello": 1, "column": [[1, float], [3, str], [4, int], [2, str]]}

columns = dic["column"]
for col in columns:
    if col[1] != float and col[1] != int:
        ind_non = columns.index(col)  # getting the index for the first non-numerical column
        break

for col in columns:
    if col[1] != str:
        ind_num = columns.index(col)  # getting the index for the first numerical column
        break

print(ind_non)
print(ind_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the first `if` condition to:

```
if col[1] != float and col[1] != int: #Will be true for non-numerical data type
```

changing the second `if` condition to:

```
if col[1] != str:                     #Will be true for numerical data type
```